# Static Readonly Properties not Returning Values Specified

Tags: c#, static, readonly

I have a class with a large number of static readonly variables that will be stored in a config file after I have it working. Among them, I have a default font size value, and a fair number of other variables that reference this default font size. One, and only one, of these variables are returning 0 rather than the default font size value.

I am having a similar issue with my FontName variables, but excluded these from the example code for brevity.

Relevant code is below, in the order it appears in my class. I tried moving the default font size declaration immediately above the body font size declaration; this caused all of the variables to return 0 rather than the default font size. Returning the declaration to its original position caused the other variables to start working again.

I also tried changing the varaiable to a static property with only a getter. This property returns the default font size as expected.

I double checked that all of the declarations listed below exist in the same scope.

And of course, I did a complete solution clean and rebuild with no change in behavior.

Also note that the variables are not throwing exceptions: they are merely returning 0.

```
//private static float _BodyFontSize { get => _DefaultFontSize; }  //returns 9
private static readonly float _BodyFontSize = _DefaultFontSize;    //returns 0

...

private void MyMethod()
{
   //where my breakpoint is at

   ...
}

...

private static readonly float _DefaultFontSize = 9;
...
private static readonly float _DetailsFontSize = _DefaultFontSize;   //returns 9
...
private static readonly float _AddressFontSize = _DefaultFontSize;   //returns 9

...

private void AnotherMethod()
{
   ...
}

...

private static readonly float _BlurbFontSize = _DefaultFontSize;  //returns 9
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Possible relevant: [When do static variables get initialized in C#?](//stackoverflow.com/q/3965976)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The language specification [static field initialization section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#static-field-initialization) explains this behavior:

> The static field variable initializers of a class correspond to a sequence of assignments that are executed in the textual order in which they appear in the class declaration. If a static constructor (Static constructors) exists in the class, execution of the static field initializers occurs immediately prior to executing that static constructor. Otherwise, the static field initializers are executed at an implementation-dependent time prior to the first use of a static field of that class.

So in your case `_BodyFontSize` is initialized before `_DefaultFontSize` and uses default value for `float` which is 0. Moving `_BodyFontSize` after `_DefaultFontSize` will fix your issue (as it does with working ones), but I think better option would be to handle this initialization in [static constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors), despite them being simple assignments.